# MySQL INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... GROUP BY is too slow

Tags: mysql, select, sql-insert

I have a table with about 50M rows and format:

```
CREATE TABLE `big_table` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `t1` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `a` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `type` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `b` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `is_c` BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `a_b_index` (a,b)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I then define the table `t2`, with no indices:

```
Create table `t2` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `a` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `b` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `t1min` DATETIME NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I then populate `t2` using a query from `big_table` (this will add about 12M rows).

```
insert into opportunities
  (id, a,b,t1min)
  SELECT id,a,b,min(t1)
    FROM big_table use index (a_b_index)
    where type='SUBMIT' and is_c=1
   GROUP BY a,b;
```

I find that it takes this query about a minute to process 5000 distinct `(a,b)` in `big_table`.
Since there are 12M distinct `(a,b)` in `big_table` then it would take about 40 hours to run 
the query on all of `big_table`.

What is going wrong?

If I just do `SELECT ...` then the query does 5000 lines in about 2s. If I `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE ...`, then the query still takes 60s for 5000 lines.

`EXPLAIN SELECT ...` gives:

```
id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,SIMPLE,stdnt_intctn_t,index,NULL,a_b_index,16,NULL,46214255,"Using where"
```

Comment: q1: how long is taking the select only?

Comment: q2: what is the explain plan of the select part?

Comment: `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` gives

Comment: Added `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SELECT ...` results above.

Comment: You would probably get benefit from 1/ removing your index hint, and 2/ adding another index on type and is_c columns (check explain plan after adding it AND doing analize table on the table)

Comment: OK.  Removing index hint gave 8% improvement;  adding an index on `type` and `is_c` gave another 8% improvement.

Comment: could you post the new explain plan please? The query might be cached that could be why it goes faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem was that the `GROUP_BY` resulted in too many random-access reads of `big_table`.  The following strategy allows one sequential trip through `big_table`.  First, we add a key to `t2`:

```
Create table `t2` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `a` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `b` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `t1min` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (a,b),
  INDEX `id` (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then we fill `t2` using:

```
insert into t2
  (id, a,b,t1min)
  SELECT id,a,b,t1
    FROM big_table
    where type='SUBMIT' and is_c=1
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
   t1min=if(t1<t1min,t1,t1min),
   id=if(t1<t1min,big_table.id,t2.id);
```

The resulting speed-up is several orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

The group by might be part of the issue.  You are using an index on (a,b), but your where is not being utilized.  I would have an index on

(type, is_c, a, b )

Also, you are getting the "ID", but not specifying which... you probably want to do a MIN(ID) for a consistent result.

Comment: I tried the index on `(type,is_c,a,b)` and it took about an hour for 5000 lines.  My guess is that the index no longer fit in the nnodb buffer pool (4GB on my machine).

Comment: The min(id) idea was helpful.